# omit vulnerability Fortify

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, fortify

good day, I have the following scenario I have a pipeline that every time it is executed creates a version in fortify, the portion of the code is

```
    container('Fortify') {
    scanFortify {
    routeScan: "src/.java" { routeScan: "src/.java" { routeScan: "src/.java"
    nameProject: env.nameProject
    }
    }
```

and call another file containing the fortify executions which would be as follows

```
    def uploadFPR(String nameProject){
    pipelineUtil.printm("Upload FPR -- App: ${nameProject} -- Version: ${BUILD_NUMBER}", "INFO")
    fortifyUpload appName: "${nameProject}", appVersion: "${BUILD_NUMBER}", resultsFile: 'code.fpr'
    }

    def call(Map pipelineParams){
    stage('Fortify'){
    if(pipelineParams.python == true){
    scan.scanFortifyPython(pipelineParams.routeScan,pipelineParams.version)
    }else{
    scan.scanFortify(pipelineParams.routeScan)
    }

    scan.uploadFPR(pipelineParams.nameProject)
    scan.verifyVulnerabilites(pipelineParams.nameProject)
    }
    }
```

and when the analysis is uploaded to fortify is giving me a critical vulnerability which I need to omit by order of my superior, is there any way either from the pipeline tell me omit this vulnerability, try to disable the vulnerability in fortify but of course as the pipeline each time you run me creates a new version is useless to do this step because in the next version I would leave the vulnerability and this does not allow me to deploy the application for this vulnerability

I hope you can give me some idea of how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Fortify, a different Version or appVersion itself does not cause this behavior if the vulnerability has been suppressed in audit once. I suspect that you have the version string as a part of filenames or directory names that are being scanned and uploaded to Fortify. In that case it will cause the vulnerability to resurface because the files in question are now being identified as new files on every scan. Give it a try after removing the version string from the file paths.